# Ошибка при сборке native hadoop library: java.net.ConnectException

Tags: ant, unix, solaris, c++, linux

Для сборки native hadoop library я выполнил две команды

```
export CPPFLAGS='-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199506L'
ant -v -DskipTests -Dcompile.native=true -Dmake.cmd=/usr/bin/gmake clean tar
```

и получил следующую ошибку:

```
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012
Trying the default build file: build.xml
Buildfile: /export/hadoop-1.0.1/build.xml
Detected Java version: 1.7 in: /opt/jdk1.7.0_06/jre
Detected OS: SunOS
parsing buildfile /export/hadoop-1.0.1/build.xml with URI = file:/export/hadoop-1.0.1/build.xml
Project base dir set to: /export/hadoop-1.0.1
parsing buildfile jar:file:/usr/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/usr/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
 [property] Loading /root/build.properties
 [property] Unable to find property file: /root/build.properties
 [property] Loading /export/hadoop-1.0.1/build.properties
 [property] Unable to find property file: /export/hadoop-1.0.1/build.properties
Override ignored for property "test.final.name"
     [exec] Current OS is SunOS
     [exec] Output redirected to property: nonspace.os
     [exec] Using input "SunOS"
     [exec] Executing 'sed' with arguments:
     [exec] 's/ /_/g'
     [exec] 
     [exec] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
     [exec] not part of the command.
Override ignored for property "make.cmd"
Property "os-arch" has not been set
Override ignored for property "build.dir"
Override ignored for property "dist.dir"
Property "clover.home" has not been set
[available] Unable to find ${clover.home}/lib/clover.jar to set property clover.present
 [macrodef] creating macro  macro_tar
Importing file /export/hadoop-1.0.1/src/test/aop/build/aop.xml from /export/hadoop-1.0.1/build.xml
Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper
parsing buildfile /export/hadoop-1.0.1/src/test/aop/build/aop.xml with URI = file:/export/hadoop-1.0.1/src/test/aop/build/aop.xml
 [property] Loading /export/hadoop-1.0.1/build.properties
 [property] Unable to find property file: /export/hadoop-1.0.1/build.properties
Property "hadoop.conf.dir.deployed" has not been set
 [macrodef] creating macro  weave-injectfault-aspects
 [macrodef] creating macro  macro-run-tests-fault-inject
 [macrodef] creating macro  macro-jar-fault-inject
 [macrodef] creating macro  macro-jar-test-fault-inject
Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper
 [macrodef] creating macro  macro-jar-examples
Property "test.fault.inject" has not been set
Property "test.fault.inject" has not been set
Property "test.fault.inject" has not been set
Property "test.fault.inject" has not been set
 [macrodef] creating macro  macro-test-runner
[available] Unable to find build/lib/ant-eclipse-1.0-jvm1.2.jar
Build sequence for target(s) `clean' is [clean-contrib, clean-sign, clean-fi, clean]
Complete build sequence is [clean-contrib, clean-sign, clean-fi, clean, java5.check, clover.setup, clover.info, clover, ivy-download, ivy-init-dirs, ivy-probe-antlib, ivy-init-antlib, ivy-init, ivy-resolve-common, ivy-retrieve-common, init, record-parser, compile-rcc-compiler, compile-core-classes, compile-hdfs-classes, compile-mapred-classes, compile-core-native, check-c++-makefiles, create-c++-pipes-makefile, create-c++-utils-makefile, compile-c++-utils, compile-c++-pipes, compile-c++, compile-core, jar, compile-tools, tools-jar, check-c++-libhdfs, check-c++-makefile-libhdfs, create-c++-libhdfs-makefile, compile-c++-libhdfs, compile-contrib, compile-ant-tasks, compile, create-c++-examples-pipes-makefile, compile-c++-examples-pipes, compile-c++-examples, compile-examples, examples, generate-test-records, compile-core-test, jar-test, ant-tasks, compile-librecordio, package-librecordio, bin-package, inject-system-faults, jar-system, jar-test-system, binary-system, create-c++-configure, aspects.inject-system-faults, ivy-resolve, aspects.jar-system, metrics.jar, patch.check, check-for-findbugs, findbugs.check, forrest.check, test-patch, check-for-checkstyle, test, ivy-resolve-checkstyle, injectfaults, run-test-core-fault-inject, test-librecordio, ivy-resolve-javadoc, compile-native, init-runAs-build, configure-runAs, run-as, ivy-retrieve-javadoc, javadoc, aspects.clean-fi, clover.check, generate-clover-reports, aspects.test-system, task-controller, test-commit, test-smoke, test-core-excluding-commit-and-smoke, test-core-all-withtestcaseonly, test-core, test-system, javadoc-dev, checkfailure, ivy-resolve-test, cn-docs, test-contrib, sign, signanddeploy, ant-task-download, mvn-taskdef, create-c++-configure-libhdfs, aspects.run-as, -classes-compilation, aspects.-compile-fault-inject, veryclean, ivy-resolve-releaseaudit, ivy-report, aspects.configure-runAs, ivy-retrieve-test, hudson-test-patch, docs, ivy-resolve-jdiff, ivy-retrieve-jdiff, write-null, api-xml, api-report, package, tar, findbugs, jar-test-fault-inject, aspects.injectfaults, binary, ivy-retrieve-releaseaudit, releaseaudit, ivy-retrieve-checkstyle, checkstyle, simpledeploy, test-cluster, rpm, jsvc, aspects.init-runAs-build, test-task-controller, jar-fault-inject, deb, set-version, mvn-deploy, ivy-retrieve, -compile-fault-inject, test-c++-libhdfs, mvn-install, changes-to-html, aspects.jar-test-system, ant-eclipse-download, eclipse, run-fault-inject-with-testcaseonly, nightly, ]

   // убраны бессмысленные логи

init-contrib:
  [antcall] Exiting /export/hadoop-1.0.1/src/contrib/capacity-scheduler/build.xml.

ivy-download:
      [get] Getting: http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.1.0/ivy-2.1.0.jar
      [get] To: /export/hadoop-1.0.1/ivy/ivy-2.1.0.jar
      [get] Error getting http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.1.0/ivy-2.1.0.jar to /export/hadoop-1.0.1/ivy/ivy-2.1.0.jar
   [subant] Exiting /export/hadoop-1.0.1/src/contrib/capacity-scheduler/build.xml.
   [subant] Exiting /export/hadoop-1.0.1/src/contrib/build.xml.

BUILD FAILED
/export/hadoop-1.0.1/build.xml:673: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/export/hadoop-1.0.1/src/contrib/build.xml:30: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/export/hadoop-1.0.1/src/contrib/build-contrib.xml:389: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:378)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:473)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:203)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:290)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:995)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:931)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:849)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Get$GetThread.openConnection(Get.java:660)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Get$GetThread.get(Get.java:579)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Get$GetThread.run(Get.java:569)

Total time: 3 minutes 31 seconds
```

Comment: спасибо, полистал )) и таки нашел автора

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Глобально у вас похоже 2 ошибки (насколько мой браузер сумел выдать перед смертью от JavaScript'а вызванного вашим постом):

1. Не задан файл `build.properties` - не спрашивайте зачем он нужен иначе я вас убью [[@ivan31](/users/4705/ivan31)](/users/4705/ivan31)
2. Ant не может загрузить внешние библиотеки находящиеся по адресу http://repo2.maven.org - что-то наверное с сетевыми настройками JVM - тоже не спрашивайте как это исправить!

P.S. Вы уже всех по-моему достали своими вопросами. Вы хотя бы раз в жизни собирали Hello World прежде чем браться за этот долб***ый Hadoop?

Answer (score 1):

У вас ошибка вот в этой строчке:

> Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012
>
> далее все убрано...

Comment: аккуратнее с такими ответами, я только со 2-го раза понял, что @Котик_хочет_кушать не автор )

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, а можно конкретнее объяснить в чем суть проблемы и что делать?

Comment: Ой ржунемогу

Comment: @ivan31 Ну я же очевидно указал, в какой строчке ошибка и что делать. Или вам не найти ничего в этом логе?

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, да лог действительно слишком большой. Не могли вы выразить свою мысль в словесной форме (при этом объяснив, что делать)?

Comment: А у меня с такими шуточками JS скрипт в мозилле виснет.

Comment: @ivan31 Извините, в словесной форме получится еще больше, так что лучше внимательно прочитайте мой ответ.

Comment: Снимаю шляпу перед упорством автора. Я бы давно уже на все плюнул и засел бы за учебники по С++, джаве, Юниксу и т.п.

Comment: Это как раз случай ненужного упорства. Вместо того, чтобы взяться за учебники - сразу садимся за штурвал звездолета.

Comment: А я вот, перед @Barmaley снимаю шляпу . Он ответил про ошибки (сам я этому автору уже перестал отвечать).

Comment: @Barmaley, я о том же.